# What is and how to produce "read-only transaction anomaly" in READ COMMITTED? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, read-committed

I read [**Analyzing a read-only transaction anomaly under snapshot isolation**](https://johann.schleier-smith.com/blog/2016/01/06/analyzing-a-read-only-transaction-anomaly-under-snapshot-isolation.html). Then, It says **read-only transaction anomaly** happens in `READ COMMITTED` and `SERIALIZABLE` in **PostgreSQL** as shown below:

[image]

Actually, I don't understand **read-only transaction anomaly** because it is complicated.

And now, I'm trying to produce **read-only transaction anomaly** in `READ COMMITTED` in **PostgreSQL** but I cannot.

My questions:

1. What is **read-only transaction anomaly?**
2. How to produce **read-only transaction anomaly** in `READ COMMITTED` in **PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 0):

A *transaction anomaly* is if the concurrent execution of several transactions produces a result that no serial execution of the transactions could have produced.

The article you reference shows exactly how the anomaly happens in the chapter “[How the anomaly occurs](https://johann.schleier-smith.com/blog/2016/01/06/analyzing-a-read-only-transaction-anomaly-under-snapshot-isolation.html#how-the-anomaly-occurs)”.

It is perfectly normal for this anomaly to occur with `READ COMMITTED`. However, it may not occur with `SERIALIZABLE`. No anomaly whatsoever is allowed to occur under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation.

Since the paper claims that it observed anomalies with PostgreSQL's `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, it must have done something wrong. I had a look at the reproducer, but it is written in a language I cannot read. Perhaps the authors misunderstood how `SERIALIZABLE` works and counted serialization errors as failures; hard to tell. What points in that direction is that they report lots of failures with Oracle. While it is a fact that Oracle's implementation of `SERIALIZABLE` is not correct (it is really `READ COMMITTED`, and they deliberately misread the SQL standard), it is an implementation that generates so many serialization failures that it is barely usable.

So while the article's first three chapters are a correct quotation, the remainder is a mixture of misunderstandings and false assertions.